# How to backup VMware fusion?

Tags: mac, backup, vmware-fusion

This might sound weird but I deleted (with a third party tool: Omnisweeper) my VMware hd disk, while it was still running. Although it is still running but I guess with next restart, it will never bootup again.

Guest OS: Ubuntu 14

Host OS: Mac ElCapitan

Can someone tell me how to take an image of it or back it up, so that I can rstore from this point again.

Comment: Why don't you just move it out of the equivalent of the recycle bin?  I seriously doubt that OS X, will delete a file, permanently without an additional user action.  I have used 15 year old versions of Unix that had a recycle bin.

Comment: I removed it with a third party tool. Omnisweeper. That never came to trash bin.

Comment: You might want to update the question to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 2):

The disk isn't really deleted by the sound of it, as it is an open file.  But it will vanish on boot.

Ubuntu will have a disk as `/dev/sda` or similar, have a look in `/dev`.  You can dd the disk image to the host using ssh:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 - | ssh yourmacuserid@machostname dd of=ubuntu.gz
```

`dd` does a byte by byte copy of the disk and pipes it through gzip to shrink, and passes the output to `ssh`.  The `ssh` command line takes the incoming stream and saves it to the .gz file.  This is a gzip compressed disk image, you can use gunzip and dd to write it to a new disk image.

Comment: Cool one liner. I would have probably also thought that you could send the dd output to a shared folder on the host

Comment: @markch Yes for sure, if you have a remote share already. This approach doesn't require anything else to be setup, and we don't want to introduce something new in a precarious situation